# Add my new website to Google search results

Tags: web, search-engine, google-search

I created a new website and published it in the web recently. The website is live 24x7 on a sub-domain .comyr.com/ . But I have tried searching my website address on google search with various keywords related t my site name & contents, even directly pasting my site url on google search box but couldn't find the link to my site in the search results.

What steps should I follow so that I can let google know about my new site and include it in its results (ofcourse to related & relivant search queries).

Thanks & Regards...

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming. Have a look at http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/about, see if it would fit and if it has not already been asked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

submit your site to Google - http://www.google.com/addurl
and learn about SEO (Search Engine Optimization).